# optimizing CSS for webpage performance

Tags: css, html

All my pages share the same css file (style.css).

To speed up my homepage, I plan to create a new CSS file using the styles that apply to the homepage (this reduces the size of the style.css file drastically).

However, some styles will be duplicated across  home.css and style.css. Apart from the maintenance overhead, are there any other disadvantages?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just created a 3rd css, "shared.css", which contains all the duplicated styles?

Alternatively, you could use something like LESS or SASS to compile 2 separate stylesheets, with only the parts that you need

Comment: Thanks all. I'm trying to avoid calling multiple css style sheets and the HTTP request overhead

Comment: Using LESS or SASS or some other CSS preprocessor allows you to compile 2 or more files into one, which means you can have 3 files (home, style, shared) and compile those into just "home" and "style" but still only have "shared" in one file

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly fine! Generally, when I code I have 2-3 different CSS files. The main one being the framework (`framework.css`), the one handling the general layout of the website (`style.css`), and the individual page one (`page.css`). Now it is perfectly fine to have multiple CSS files, and even some overlap. The extra time it takes will be nominal.